# UIViewController and UITableViewController shared logic

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I have a class called `BaseViewController` that inherits from `UIViewController` and a class called `BaseTableViewController` that inherits from `UITableViewController`. Both of these classes have identical shared logic (i.e. rotation handling, helper methods, etc.). Right now the code is simply duplicated in both. I've considered just making a ViewControllerHelper class and exposing it as a public property, but I was wondering if there were any more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need any shared ivars/properties, you could write an extension for UIViewController

Comment: Brilliant, a superb idea, I don't need any ivars or properties, just helper methods so this is perfect!

Comment: Hmmm. What do you suggest if someone needs extra properties? I'm have been thinking about this same problem. Composition doesn't seem ideal as we'd have to write wrappers for all shared methods.

Comment: @jonathan-cichon extension cannot provide implementation, right? In this case, you have to provide the same implementation in UIViewController and UITableViewController?

Comment: @DavidLiu you are kind of limited with properties and ivars in your extensions but you can work around those limitations with `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject`

Comment: @JonathanCichon I didn't mean properties. What I meant was extension only provides method declaration, not implementation.

Comment: @DavidLiu No, you can do method implementations in extensions or categories.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a common class like `BaseViewController` with two initializers:

`initWithList:` (for table view) and `initWithSomething:` for simple UIViewController stuff. Each of those initializers would load separate xibs (one with the `UITableView` as main view, other - as simple `UIView`).

You'd have the same methods in every instance. And it would only need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.